# Changing mobile menu header text

Tags: menu

I'm trying to find where I change the text of the mobile menu. I want to change the Home/Account section to Home/Accounts & info.

Any suggestions of where I should be looking to edit the file?

[image: Where to change menu]

Answer (score 2):

Create file in `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` and put below code in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="store.links">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Account &amp; Info</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="store.menu">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Navigation</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: @John Jones, did this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

> **module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml**

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="store.menu" group="navigation-sections" template="Magento_Theme::html/container.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Menu</argument>
    </arguments>
    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="Magento_Theme::html/topmenu.phtml" ttl="3600" before="-"/>
</block>
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="store.links" group="navigation-sections">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[Accounts & Info]]></argument>
        <argument name="use_force" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
        <argument name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<!-- Account links -->]]></argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to **vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml**

```
 <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="store.menu" group="navigation-sections" template="Magento_Theme::html/container.phtml">
   <arguments>
       <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Menu</argument>
   </arguments>
<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="Magento_Theme::html/topmenu.phtml" ttl="3600" before="-"/>
</block>
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="store.links" group="navigation-sections">
   <arguments>
      <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Accounts & info</argument>
      <argument name="use_force" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
      <argument name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<!-- Account links -->]]> 
      </argument>
  </arguments>
</block>
```